# How to allocate more memory to anaconda(jupyter)

Tags: python-3.x, windows, memory, anaconda, jupyter

I have 16g ram laptop, but when i try to run python code in jupyter inside Anaconde, it take ages to run and only consume 40% or less from the memory, how i can allocate more memory so that my code runs faster?
its windows 10 OS

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried anything that didn't work yet? If so, please include that information. I have a feeling that if it is taking up 40% of your available memory, allocating more to it is not going to speed it up. What is your processor like?

Comment: I don't think memory alone is the reason for slow performance. From my experience, jupyter will avail all memory you have till it reaches a memory error. Execution speed has a lot to do with the way your script is written, and with your processor.

Comment: for example this command take up to 8 hours running , loading without error and no output just loading till i end it  :                                                                                               
# Create a "subgraph" of just the largest component
# calculate the diameter of the subgraph.
subgraph = G.subgraph(largest_component)
diameter = nx.diameter(subgraph)
print("Network diameter of largest component:", diameter)